# Editing a List<T> in between two windows forms (C#)

Tags: c#, forms, list

I have a query regarding maintaining a List in between two windows forms. It's for a project where I need to create an address book.

I have chosen to maintain the contact details in the form of a List. My first windows form (form1) contains a master copy of a list `AddressBook`, which contains the address book. 
I hardcoded 4 entries into the address book list in order to experiment and get the simple functions such as 'add' and 'edit' working.

I have a second windows form called Add, in which I can add new entries to the list. This works fine. I can add a new contact in the ADD form and this shows up in the initial form1, master form.

My problem arises in the EDIT form. I pass the AddressBook (master) list to the EDIT form. The EDIT form takes the master list and I am able to manipulate the records in that list. However when it comes to sending back the new list to the master page (form1), it does not pick it up. I am using the same code as I do in the ADD form which successfully sends back the new list. However this code does not work when sending back an edited list.

Here is my AddressBook property within form1

```
public List<Contact> addressBook;
    public List<Contact> AddressBook
    {

       get { return addressBook;} 
       set {addressBook = value;} 

    }
```

Within EDIT:

```
public Edit()

    {
        InitializeComponent();           
        temp = Master.AddressBook;    // temp is the temporary List I update within EDIT         

    }
```

** I then have my algorithm which successfully lets me EDIT the list temp. the list temp now has the edited list****

then when I hit the save button, I use the following code;

```
Master.AddressBook = temp;
```

All I need is for the list temp to be sent back to form1.

the code `Master.AddressBook = temp;` WORKS for when I add values to the list through the ADD form.

ADD FORM:

```
 public Add()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        temp = Master.AddressBook;


    }


       **** code to add a new record into the list temp. the new record is called newRecord**********



    private void btnAddClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stor.AddressBook = temp; // when I hit close on the form, it updates the master     list AddressBook 
        this.Close(); 
    }
```

This is all probably very poorly worded but in essence the only bit where my code fails is when I want to change my master Addressbook within form1 by replacing it with the list temp, which is the edited list from my EDIT form.

I think it's something to do with my AddressBook property. But this doesn't explain why I can replace AddressBook with a list containing new records but I can't replace it with a list containing edited records.

Comment: Since `List<T>` is a reference type, once you use `temp = Master.AddressBook`, both refer to the same instance. You don't have to copy anything back, changing items via `temp` also changes items in `Master.AddressBook`. Something else must be going on - could you focus on the differences between the Add and Edit operations?

Comment: Not only should you not need to set the list again (since it's the same list) you shouldn't need to access that list to change any items.  For the edit form you only need to pass in a single `Contact` and mutate that; as long as it's a reference type, which it should be.

Comment: What you're editing? The AddressBook or the Contact

Comment: @ Evenhuis there aren't many differences between Add and Edit. In fact, in both instances I looked at temp before closing the windows. temp is correct in both forms. only when I close ADD, the AddressBook list has correctly been edites but when i close EDIT it's not

Comment: @Nasmi I am editing a contact within the AddressBook list

Comment: How do you pass the contact to your Edit method? Is Contact a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to make the list in Master static.

Master:

```
    public static List<Contact> AddressBook { get; set; }
```

Note: You do not need the backing variable, and if you do want to use it, best practices would suggest that it be private.  If you do decide to use it, it will also need to be static.

In the Add form, you would then gather the data to create a new Contact object and temp should, in fact, be *just* a Contact object.
Add Form:

```
private Contact newRecord = null;
public Add()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    newRecord = new Contact();
}

/**** code to add the user-input to the new Contact object ****/

private void btnAddClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Master.AddressBook.Add(newRecord);
    this.Close(); 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I don't think my post was very clear but my add form works fine. It's the edit form that's the issue. I pass a single contact from AddressBook to the edit form. Within this form I want to edit the contact and send it back to the original master list, AddressBook.

Answer (score 0):

This is where the `Singleton` pattern comes in handy: [Implementing Singleton in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

You will notice *Application Settings* uses this same patttern to allow you to globally access it without having to pass it around.

When I use a `Singleton` I typically make the class name like **(TypeName)Manager** (ex: **AddressBookManager**).

So the class might be something like this:

```
public static class AddressBookManager
{
  #region Singleton
  static readonly AddressBookManager instance = new AddressBookManager();

  private AddressBookManager(); // prevent creating instances of this

  public static AddressBookManager Current { get { return instance; } }
  #endregion

  AddressBook master = new AddressBook(); // the master address book

  public AddressBook Master
  { 
    get { return master; }  // get the master address book
    set { master = value; } // set the master address book
  }
}
```

Then in each form you would access it like so:

```
var addressBook = AddressBookManager.Current.Master; 
addressBook.Add(newRecord);
```

The problem you are experiencing with the *Edit* functionality probably has something to do with the way you are using temporary lists. By using a static, global list and merely adding/editing items inside of it, you don't run that problem. Since your `Contact` items are a `class` (**not `struct`**), their changes will be reflected in the list automatically since they are reference types.

The great part about `Singleton` classes is the ability to access them from anywhere in the project. The only caveat is that you need to be extra cautious when working with multi-threaded applications and `Singleton` classes.